# Mockery, Codeception and Symfony - Cannot redeclare class

Tags: symfony, codeception, mockery

I have the following part of an existing unit test (with Mockery as enabled module):

```
$mockedEvent = \Mockery::mock('\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent');
```

This test runs fine and is successful, but as soon as Codeception reaches my functional tests with Symfony2 module I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, because the name is already in use in /projectDir/var/bootstrap.php.cache on line 365
```

Somehow the declared classes in my unit tests are causing problems in my functional tests, which leads to me not being able to use Mockery as intended. How do I avoid this error?

Comment: Please run Codeception with -vvv flag and add complete stack trace to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This error disappeared when upgrading Codeception to 2.2. - although now Codeception often segfaults when reaching the functional tests, and only works again when running the functional tests only (which works) and then the whole test suite runs fine again. Always something weird going on with Codeception in my experience.